# build failure in dyn.js

Tags: maven, build

Today I tried to build dyn.js from source with the instructions on https://github.com/dynjs/dynjs.
I tried it on Windows 7 and Linux (Fedora), but on both systems the build fails.
This is what i get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building dynjs 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.projectodd.rephract:rephract:jar:1.x.incremental.39 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.jboss.jreadline:jreadline:jar:0.20.incremental.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.jruby.joni:joni:jar:1.1.10.incremental.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.382s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 20 12:01:04 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dynjs: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.dynjs:dynjs:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.projectodd.rephract:rephract:jar:1.x.incremental.39, org.jboss.jreadline:jreadline:jar:0.20.incremental.2, org.jruby.joni:joni:jar:1.1.10.incremental.1: Failure to find org.projectodd.rephract:rephract:jar:1.x.incremental.39 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or how to get a working version of dyn.js?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version # for that dependency has just been updated,  see here:

https://github.com/dynjs/dynjs/blob/master/pom.xml#L144

so if you pull the repo,  it should fix that and here is a link to the 0.1.1 tag

https://github.com/dynjs/dynjs/tree/v0.1.1

Once the sonatype ends its maintenance, 0.1.1 should be released in central

-Luke

Comment: But now I have another problem/question. Is it possible to compile a javascript with dyn.js to a java class file or is it only possible to interpret with dyn.js?

Comment: just interpret.  what would be the use case for javascript -> java?

Comment: I do a project with tracking invokedynamic calls, so it would be nice to have '.class' files, because then I can see the method signatures in the deassembled bytecode.